# tHow to fix my landscape-sysinfo text formatting?

Tags: landscape, motd

I was using ubuntu minimized, but it doesnt come with landscape-sysinfo, so I instaled it but now isnt on the right output format, one-column, I want it two-column

[My landscape-sysinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvH3U.png)

[Example of a right landscape-sysinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f30lm.png)

My version: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: To make it easier to resolve your issue, please edit your question to include the Ubuntu OS version (22.04.2?). Also, is your issue related to the output font, or the format of the output itself (one-column vs. two-column)? It's unclear to me based on your question as written. Thanks